# How to prevent inserting "." "/" and "\" into SQL database as empty string

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework-6, special-characters

in my code I have this

```
string specialChar = @"\|!#$%&/()=?»«@£§€{}.-;'<>_,";
```

What I'm trying to achieve, is that I'm trying to insert every single character from this string into database, and database every time should throw an exception, because it has a constraint, allowing only letters and numbers to be inserted.

All works good, except for three characters - `".", "/" and "\".`

Somehow these values still get inserted into table, because they are converted into empty strings. I'm not sure why, but maybe `EF6` is doing that.

Sadly, adding a constraint for not allowing `empty/NULL` values is not an option.

Any ideas why and how to prevent these characters conversion to empty strings?

```
byte[] data = new byte[] { 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20 };

foreach (var item in specialChar)
{
    try
    {
        string tempName = item.ToString();
        upload.Upload(tempName, data);
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       // this is not being thrown at specified characters
    }
}
```

Constraint I'm using to prevent special characters:

```
CONSTRAINT [ck_No_Special_Characters] CHECK (NOT [name] like '%[^A-Z0-9]%')
```

Upload.cs

```
        var db = new testEntities();
        var fileToUpload = new testFile();

        // **this is where I'm using my chars** 
        fileToUpload.name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(name);
        fileToUpload.extension = Path.GetExtension(name);
        fileToUpload.data = data;

        db.test.Add(fileToUpload);
        db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Do you have an example of where you are storing those values and it is unexpectedly working? How/where are you applying your test for `specialChar` - can we see that please?

Comment: Whats does you constraint look like? How are you inserting them into SQL?Have you tried raw SQL does this work?

Comment: That code really doesn't help... What does upload do, whats in data...etc. etc. Please read the instructions on how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem

Comment: You are using regex in your constraint. Are you sure it works?

Comment: Raw SQL prevents from inserting, so I think constraints are ok... Now I'm thinking its the Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension() which gives the problem. Can it be?

Comment: Already done using the verbatim `@` @Alex

Comment: I think It is the method I'm getting my filename from. But I'm not sure how to change it so it works accordingly

Answer (score 0):

This should be handled at the front end itself instead of going to database level. Imagine an invalid file name reaching database, it rejects due to your constraints and reports back to UI. You are wasting resources.

Handling this at UI will save unnecessary database calls.

Use **GetInvalidFileNameChars** method:

```
if (name.IndexOfAny(System.IO.Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()) == -1)
{
    var db = new testEntities();
    var fileToUpload = new testFile();

    // **this is where I'm using my chars** 
    fileToUpload.name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(name);
    fileToUpload.extension = Path.GetExtension(name);
    fileToUpload.data = data;

    db.test.Add(fileToUpload);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Filename has invalid characters");
}
```